# awk system syntax throwing error

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to move all my files in my directory individually to a new directory phonex and rename them at the same time phonex.txt.
so e.g.

`1.txt, 2.txt, jim.txt`

become:

```
phone1.txt in directory phone1
phone2.txt in directory phone2
phone3.txt in directory phone3.
```

I'm a newbie to awk, but I have managed to create the directories, but I cannot get the rename right. 
I have tried:

```
ls|xargs -n1|awk ' {i++;system("mkdir phone"i);system("mv "$0" phone”i ”.txt -t phone"i)}'
```

which errors with lots of:

```
mv: cannot stat `phone”i': No such file or directory
```

and:

```
ls|xargs -n1|awk ' {i++;system("mkdir phone"i);system("mv "$0" phone”i ”/phone"i”.txt”)}'
```

error:

```
awk: 1: unexpected character 0xe2
```

xargs: /bin/echo: terminated by signal 13
Can anyone help me finish it off? TIA!

Comment: Looks like a simple case of using `”` instead of `"`.

Comment: In general, and in particular if you're a beginner, the use of `system` is quite dangerous.  If you had put together a syntactically correct program that did the wrong thing, `system` would happily, e.g., spray all your files across the file system... (note that I'm not implying this is the case with your program, I'm discussing a possibility).  I prefer to print the commands on stdout and examine the output of the program before applying it, and only when I'm pretty confident in the correctness of my work I (1) pipe the output to `| sh` or (2) change `print ...` with `system(...)`.

Comment: Now, a more specific comment: you're **duplicating** information by placing `file1` in `folder1`, `file2` in `folder2` etc.  Sometimes redundancy is good engineering, sometimes is waste.

Comment: Why are you using awk ? It literally offers zero advantage in this case. xargs already loops through all the files.

Comment: @jidder because I don't know any better. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Yes a simple bash loop could do what you want

Comment: I agree with @TomFenech there's two type of double quotes in your command line, if this a copy paste result or are the quotes really different here `"mv "$0" phone”i ”/phone"i”.txt”` as exemple. your first error sounds like it is the case really, change the `”`by `"` (see the difference between non-ascii and ascii one) and you should get what you wish.

Comment: @Tom Fenech, looks like you are right, I had no idea different font double quote would make a difference.

Comment: You are using shell to call awk to call system to call shell to call mkdir/mv. That's GOT to be raising some red flags surely? Just have shell call mkdir/mv and get rid of all the unnecessary stuff in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted it with incrementing numbers.
Else Tom Fenech's way is the way to go !

```
for i in *.txt;do d=phone$((++X));mkdir "$d"; mv "$i" "$d/$d.txt";done
```

Also you may want to set x to zero `x=0` before doing this in case it is already set as something else

Comment: Comments cleaned :) I do prefer @TomFenech one as it try to copy only if directory creation is ok (but this could have other side effects too)

Answer (score 3):

Piping `ls` into `xargs` into `awk` is completely unnecessary in this scenario. What you are trying to do can be accomplished using a simple loop:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    i=$((i+1))
    dir="phone$i"
    mkdir "$dir" && mv "$f" "$dir/$dir.txt"
done
```

Depending on your shell, the increment of `$i` can be done in a different way (like `((++i))` in bash) but this way is POSIX-compliant so should work on any modern shell.

By the way, the reason for your original error is that you are using curly quotes `”`, which are not understood by the shell. You should always only use single `'` and double `"` in the shell.